# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to add data into db with all first words as capital letter. But it's shows error syntax error.

> unexpected ',', expecting ']',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

**Model**

```php
protected $fillable = [
     'category_name',
     'category_description',
     'category_slug',
     'category_image'
];

public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes[
        'category_name',
        'category_description',
        'category_slug',
        'category_image'
    ] = strtoupper($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

```
public function setCategoryNameAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['category_name'] = strtoupper($value);
}
```

Or

```
public function setCategoryNameAttribute($value)
{
    return strtoupper($value);
}
```

If you want to do with all field then you may have define the function for all.

Comment: i tried the above one it is making all the words capital i just need only first alphabet of every word capital like ucfirst

Comment: use ucfirst instead of strtoupper.

Comment: category name contains on two words alpha brave ucfirst only makes Alpha bravo i need Aplha Bravo.........how to do it

Comment: use ucwords dude.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `setFirstNameAttribute($value)` mutator function is wrong. Mustator is only for one attribute. So you have to create multiple mutators for every attribute.

Possible answer. If you want to mutate `category_name`.

```php
public function setCategoryNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->category_name = strtoupper($value);
}
```

And if you want to mutate `category_description`

```php
public function setCategoryDescriptionAttribute($value)
{
   $this->category_description = strtoupper($value);
}
```

likewise you need to define multiple mutators to all the other attributes.

**EDIT**

if you want to make only to capitalize the first letter of words use `title_case()` instead of `strtoupper()`

```php
public function setCategoryDescriptionAttribute($value)
{
   $this->category_description = title_case($value);
}
```

Comment: at closing bracket of it public function setCategoryNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->category_name = strtoupper($value)
    }

Comment: Ignore my syntax errors :) Get the idea from the answer :)

Comment: Why a down vote? This is the most standard suggestion and the best answer.

Comment: This isn't actually true. You can work with any number of attributes in a mutator. I probably isn't a good idea but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->attributes[
    'category_name',
    'category_description',
    'category_slug',
    'category_image'
] = strtoupper($value);
```

You can't set multiple array values at once like this. You would have to set them separately or in a loop:

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_names = [
        'category_name',
        'category_description',
        'category_slug',
        'category_image',
    ];

    foreach ($attribute_names as $attribute_name) {
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = strtoupper($value);
    }
}
```